# How do I simplify $\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For a given positive integer $n$, how do I simplify $$\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)?$$

By simplification I mean is there any formula which makes it easier to compute it (rather than just compute each term and sum up)?

Comment: Well, if $n$ is prime, then there is a very simple formula.

Comment: @amcalde I know that, but I'm interested in the general case. Say $n=\prod_{t=1}^{s}p_t^{\alpha_t}$ is the standard factorization. Is it possible to express this sum with $p_t$'s and $\alpha_t$'s?

Comment: Group things by the $\gcd$. $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \gcd (k,n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant k \leqslant n \\ \gcd(k,n) = d}} d.$$

Comment: What do you need this for? It sounds vaguely like the kind of things some online programming challenges ask to have computed.

Comment: Useful paper: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/BROUGHAN/gcdsum.pdf Simple explanation: https://forthright48.com/gcd-sum-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as a complement to other answers, we may notice that the arithmetic function
$$ S(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d\cdot\varphi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right) = (\text{Id}*\varphi)(n) $$
is a multiplicative function, since it is the Dirichlet's convolution between two multiplicative functions. So in order to compute $S(n)$ for any $n\geq 1$, it is enough to compute $S(p^k)$ when $p$ is a prime number:
$$ S(p^k) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} p^{k-j} \varphi(p^{j}) = p^k+(p-1)\sum_{j=1}^{k}p^{k-j}p^{j-1}=p^k+k(p-1)p^{k-1}$$
and:
$$ S(n) = n\prod_{p\mid n}\left[1+\nu_p(n)\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right].$$

Answer (score 4):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$Use the following two facts

1. if $G$ is a multiplicative group of order $n$, generated by $g$, and $k$ is an integer, then the order of $g^{k}$ is 
   $$
   \frac{n}{\gcd(n, k)}
   $$
2. in a cyclic group $G$ of order $n$, there are $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$, for each divisor $d$ of $n$

Let $D$ be the set of positive divisors of $n$. Let $d \in D$, so that also $n/d \in D$. In the summation 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n)$$
we get a term $n/d$ every time that $g^{k}$ has order $d$ in a cyclic group $\langle g \rangle$ of order $n$, so $\phi(d)$ times.

Your summation becomes
$$
\sum_{d \in D} \phi(d) \frac{n}{d}.
$$
But perhaps this is not that much better than the original. Although, as suggested in a comment below by Henning Makholm, one can obtain from this a formula in terms of the prime factorization of $n$, as requested by OP in a comment to the post.

Comment: And now there's a simple formula for $\frac{\phi(d)}{d}$ in terms of the prime factorization of $d$ ... which if I'm keeping things straight ought to mean everything collapses to something like $$n \prod_i \Bigl(1+\alpha_i\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\Bigr) = \prod_i(1+(\alpha_i+1)(p_i-1))$$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, sure!

Comment: That is ${\phi (d)\over d} =\prod_{p|d}(1-{1\over p})$, p being prime

Comment: It seems there are two equivalent forms of the sum over divisors. See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, well, of course, because $d \leftrightarrow n/d$ is a bijection on the set of positive divisors of $n$.

Comment: I get following this that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,n) = n \prod_i (1+\alpha_i(1-{1\over p_i}))$$ where $i$ where $$n = \prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$$ and it seems to check out with the sequence provided by the OEIS

Answer (score 2):

This function is called *Pillai's arithmetical function* and is [A018804](https://oeis.org/A018804) in the OEIS. Values of the function starting from $n=1$ are as follows:
$$1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 15, 13, 20, 21, 27, 21, 40,\dots$$
Vladeta Jovovic in the comments there gives this formula which ranges only over the divisors of $n$:
$$\sum_{d\mid n}d\cdot\varphi(n/d)$$
which is the same sum as obtained by Andreas Caranti (above).